# Python: Float needs to return with space after a negative

Tags: python

I can't figure out the correct way to make this happen.

If I have an input of `float("- 4")`, I want it to return `-4.0`, regardless of the blank, or whitespace. So this needs to work with other inputs like `" -   4"`, as well. But I don't want this to compromise any other results of the function, so inputs like `"4 -"`, or `"5 5"` should not be compounded as well.

I wrote a function to try and determine if something is the correct input for my program.

```
def isNum(num):

   try:
       float(expr)
   except ValueError:
       return False
   return True
```

It's just the whole input issue above that is frustrating me.

Comment: you can delete whitespaces by replacing them with nothing (`string.replace(" ", "")`). Sorry, what's your desired output for "4 -" or "5 5"?

Comment: So you only want to remove whitespace between `-` and a digit? You could probably write a regex for that.

Comment: If the input is "4 -" or "5 5", I just want float() to return the usual conversion error. Only in the situation of a minus followed by a number, regardless of white space, do I want it to compound the input into a single number.

Answer (score 2):

Simply strip the whitespace between `-` and any digits to the right:

```
import re
def parse_float(inp):
    return float(re.sub(r'-\s*(\d)', r'-\1', inp))
```

Example:

```
>>> parse_float("  -  4  ")
-4.0
>>> parse_float(" 5 ")
5.0
```

And it'll fail with `ValueError` for invalid floats:

```
>>> parse_float("  4 - ")
...
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4 - 
>>> parse_float(" 5 5 ")
...
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 5 5
```